How to fix bad file descriptor error on laravel?
When accessing my Laravel application the following error shows up:

fwrite(): Write of 4278 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor

I've tried the following options:

chmod -R 775 storage bootstrap/cache
php artisan config:clear/view:clear/cache:clear
php artisan storage:link
composer update

My PHP version is 8.3.12 and Laravel 11.26.0.
This error appear when the public/index.php is called and reach this line:
$response = $kernel->handle(

    $request = Request::capture()

)->send()


You need to verify that you have enough space on the server and try assigning ownership to the proper web server user.

What does your controller do?

@Olivier It calls for external services to render the info. on a view.

@IwalewaFawaz I'm running it locally using Laravel Herd, any thoughts on how to assign ownership to the server user?

The error could occur for many reasons. You need to check some issues:

Check File System Permissions and Ownership
Check Disk Space or File System Issues
File Descriptor Limits
Session/Log Storage Issues
Disable Opcode Cache Temporarily
Check Web Server Logs


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
